# Designing a polyphonic synth

Tags: music, synthesizer, midi

I am currently designing a synth based on various designs online and modifying them([the vco](http://www.birthofasynth.com/Thomas_Henry/Pages/VCO-1.html#Voltage_Controlled_Oscillator:_VCO-1)). I am not sure what I'm going to use in between the MIDI and VCO. What parts/circuits would I need to add/replace in order to make this synth polyphonic?

Comment: Multiple analog channels are required (one per voice) surely?

Comment: What pjc50 says plus you need a means to assign notes to channels and to implement channel stealing whereby new notes take over the channels of oldest notes (e.g. when concurrently pressing 5th key on a 4-channel synth).

Comment: You need logarithmic VCOs too to ensure that multiple VCO frequencies remain harmonically locked when you drive multiple VCOs.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick aka what would you guys recommend for creating multiple analog channels. Also I can't seem to find any logarithmic VCOs online.

Comment: This looks promising: http://www.ladyada.net/make/x0xb0x/fab/vco.html. That page in particular, but also the actual project: http://www.ladyada.net/make/x0xb0x/index.html, though I don't think it's a *polyphonic* synth.

Comment: Electronics Today International (ETI) published a design for Tim Orr's [Transcendent PolySynth](http://www.matrixsynth.com/2010/08/powertran-transcendent-polysynth.html) in 1978. I remember the articles address many of the problems you will face and may be worth a read if you can find them online. This is all pre-MIDI.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at how Roland etc did it:

- CPU decodes MIDI / scans keyboard matrix / computes envs and LFOs / etc
- Single DAC (CPU writes the CV for every parameter one by one in a loop)
- 4051 8:1 muxes connect the DAC to the S/Hs one by one (controlled by CPU)
- Each S/H is a capacitor (to store CV when not connected to DAC) and an OP-AMP

Only polyphonic analog synth I'm aware of that doesn't do this is CS-80.